# Generating function for number of compositions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I don't know how to solve this combinatorics problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $h_0=1$ and let $h_n$ be the number of compositions of $n$ into parts equal to $2$ or $3$.  Find a closed formula for $H(x)=\sum\limits_{n≥0} h_n x^n$.

Comment: There is a simple recurrence for $h_n$ which is then easily translated into a generating function.  Can you at least find the recurrence?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oops, thanks for the correction!

Comment: Hint: What is the generating function for the number of compositions of $n$ into parts equal to $2$? What is the generating function for the number of compositions of $n$ into parts equal to $3$? How is $H(x)$ related to those two simpler generating functions?

Comment: I rewrote the right hand side of H(x) as follows: 1 + (x^2 +x^3) +(x^2 +x^3)^2 + (x^2 +x^3)^3 + ... This is a geometric series and the coefficient of x^n is actually h_n.  Therefore, H(x) = 1/[1 - (x^2 +x^3)].